# How to fix list card in IE11 ?images are Big (css Grid) Crhome ,Safari works well

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

```css
.section-wrap-container1 {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.category__01 {
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  align-item: center;
}

.cards1 {
  display: grid;
  margin: auto 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(190px, 1fr));
  /* see notes below */
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  -ms-grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(190px, 1fr));
  /* see notes below */
  -ms-grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
  -ms-grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
  /*height: 200px;*/
  /*background: red;*/
  border: 2px solid #b2b6ba;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: .5rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  /* -webkit-box-orient: vertical; */
  /* -webkit-box-direction: normal; */
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  color: #5d5e5e;
  &:hover {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.2);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.2);
    top: -4px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background-color: white;
  }
}


/* li item */

.thumbnail {
  margin: 14px;
}

.thumbnail img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  align-item: center;
  margin: 0px;
}

.category_01>.box-img {
  margin: 0;
}

.card-content {
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  color: #282d32;
}

.p-add {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffae42;
  //border: 0.1em solid #b2b6ba;
}

//.p-add:hover {color:grey;}
.page-header {
  color: #E58A05;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.link-content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  //background-color:#DFE3E8;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.brk-btn {
  position: relative;
  background: #4c4c4c;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0.1em solid orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.6em 0.9em;
  font-size: 65%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: 1.15;
  /* 1 */
  margin: 0;
  /* 2 */
}
```

```html
<section class="section-wrap-container1">
  <div class="cards1">
    <article class="card">
      <picture class="thumbnail">
        <div class="category__01">
          <a href="https://jarukindustries.co.uk/collections/aerosols">
            <img class="box-img" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2346/2303/files/Aerosols_for_Homepage.jpg?22675" alt="Aerosols collection jar uk industries">
          </a>
        </div>
      </picture>
      <div class="link-content">
        <a href="https://jarukindustries.co.uk/collections/aerosols" class="p-add"><button class="brk-btn">Aerosols</button></a>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="card">
      <picture class="thumbnail">
        <div class="category__01">
          <a href="https://jarukindustries.co.uk/collections/chemicals-sprays">
            <img class="box-img" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2346/2303/files/chemicals_2_Collection_Homepage.jpg?22663" alt="Chemicals collection jar uk industries">
          </a>
        </div>
      </picture>
      <div class="link-content">
        <a href="https://jarukindustries.co.uk/collections/chemicals-sprays" class="p-add"><button class="brk-btn">Chemicals</button></a>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

I added this code to the site homepage.
It's a list of cards and I used css grid. On Chrome, Safari, android and Ios phone works fine. On IE11 it displays the very large images one below the other. I attach the image on chrome (which is fine) and on IE11. Yes, and someone knows how to solve the problem. Thank you so much

image on Chrome,Safari: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2346/2303/files/Screenshot_2019-08-23_at_12.18.05.png?23462

image on Chrome,Safari: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2346/2303/files/IMG_2971_1.jpg?23461

Comment: Hey Andrea, The issue in IE browser is `auto-fill` of `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(190px, 1fr));`  in `.cards1`.
Currently IE does not support `auto-fill` and `auto-fit`.

Comment: thank you so much sbrrk,
do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: can you please try this css once and let me know is it working? or not..

`grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
-ms-grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);`

Comment: Thanks again for your help , seems not to work, overlaps all the cards on all cards.

Comment: then can you please follow this guide of Grid Layout [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

I hope from this you can find the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much , I'm going to see the link

Comment: it's difficolt for me..I tried ..just this autofill...but I don't understand

Comment: sorry, i am also not expert of grid layout but if you change grid layout to float i can defiantly help you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [grid-template-columns repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) property doesn't support IE browser, I have tried to remove it and using the following CSS style:

```
<style>
    .section-wrap-container1 {
        max-width: 1400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .cards1 {
        overflow: auto;
        display: block;
    }

        .cards1 > .card {
            margin: 20px;
            width: 15%;
            float: left;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
        }
    .card {
        /*height: 200px;*/
        /*background: red;*/
        border: 2px solid #b2b6ba;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: .5rem;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        -ms-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        /* -webkit-box-orient: vertical; */
        /* -webkit-box-direction: normal; */
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: relative;
        color: #5d5e5e;
        min-height:200px;
        min-width:180px;
        /*&:hover

    {
        transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.2);
        -ms-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.2);
        box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.2);
        top: -4px;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
        background-color: white;
    }*/
    }

    .category__01 {
        display: block;
        border: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        align-item: center;
    }

    /* li item */

    .thumbnail {
        margin: 14px;
        height:16vw;
        max-height:200px;
        min-height:150px;

    }

        .thumbnail img {
            width: 100%;
            align-item: center;
            margin: 0px;
        }

    .category_01 > .box-img {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .card-content {
        font-size: 1rem;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
        text-align: center;
        color: #282d32;
    }

    .p-add {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #ffae42;
        /*//border: 0.1em solid #b2b6ba;*/
    }

    /*//.p-add:hover {
        color: grey;
    }*/

    .page-header {
        color: #E58A05;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .link-content {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
        text-align: center;
        /*//background-color:#DFE3E8;*/
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-top:10px;
    }

    .brk-btn {
        position: relative;
        background: #4c4c4c;
        color: white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 0.1em solid orange;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 0.6em 0.9em;
        font-size: 65%;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        /* 1 */
        line-height: 1.15;
        /* 1 */
        margin: 0;
        /* 2 */
    }

    @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
        /* IE10+ CSS */
        .link-content {
            margin-bottom: 50px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

The result like this:

[image]

More detail information, please check [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/6sbLr2nu/).

Comment: thank you very much you save meeeeeeee thank you works I don't have words

Comment: Sorry I still have problems, when I try it on IE 11 I see that the text of the button comes out of the card, and all the cards are moved a little to the left not perfectly in the center.
I have created 12 cards I would like to keep them as the initial code ie 6 for each line in the browser view.
Do you think it's better that you only use Flebox so you work the same with IE? ... I can't get the same results ...

Comment: Try to refer to the following code sample: http://jsfiddle.net/owcdL6tg/

Comment: I tried now a code like yours , using only Flexbox,it seems to work well .

Comment: I just have to improve the way I see it on two objects placed side by side on Mobile view, because now I see them under the other

Comment: I can,t decide with media query the number of card on the row?

Comment: for example media(max-width:1200px){ .card{margin:0.2em; width:18%;}} to have 4 card a 1200px screen but no work for me ..

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the number of card on the row? If that is the case, you could change the following code: ` .product-card {
                flex: 1 46%;
            }`, by change the flex-basis property (the percentage). More detail about CSS media, please check [Media Rules](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: Yes Zhi Lv - MSFT , I have create a container .card List whit max-whit:1400px; display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; and space around..and after I have create the cards inside .card-Home whit { margin:0.2em; width:14%; height:auto...(without insert display:flex; on the cards only to the container..it seems work better but when I have create the media to instruct the card to 1200px to have 4 cards instead 6 cards....no work the code above in the last message

Comment: it seems that the cointainer (.card-list) leave always the big margin on the left and right I can't leave on media@......until 690px it is perfect after if I resize the screen it put the cards on 1 Card column and leave this big margin on the side......

Comment: Can you share the latest code you are using? You could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to describe it.